# Xml data extraction?

Tags: php, foreach

Xml source:

```
<nodes>
<TUR>
<node>
<kaynakad>Veri</kaynakad>
<rast>xxx1</rast>
<saat>18:50</saat>
</node>
<node>
<kaynakad>Veri</kaynakad>
<rast>xxx5</rast>
<saat>18:50</saat>
</node>
</TUR>
</nodes>
```

Used in the loop:

```
<?php foreach ($ev->TUR->children() as $node) { ?>
```

Show:

```
<?php echo $kaynakad=$node->kaynakad. '</br>'; ?>
<?php echo $rast=$node->rast. '</br>'; ?>
<?php echo $saat=$node->saat. '</br>'; ?>
```

**kaynakad** and **saat** no problem. But, **rast** problem.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest: simplexml_load_string

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: Look at the example I gave. For the sample foreach loop? I little know English, sorry.